# How do I upload a specific file using the google drive API

Tags: powershell, pdf, google-drive-api

I'm using powershell to upload a PDF from a local computer to my google drive using the google drive api. Currently I'm using an adapted version of [Montel Edwards](https://monteledwards.com/2017/03/05/powershell-oauth-downloadinguploading-to-google-drive-via-drive-api/)' code. When I run my code it creates a google drive file as intended but instead of following the instructions specified in $GUploadBody it creates an untitled document who's contents are the literal text of that variable. What should I change so that the actual pdf is uploaded.

Here's my code, hopefully it formatted correctly when i uploaded it

```
   $refresh_body = @{

    client_id='redacted';
    client_secret='redacted';
    refresh_token='redacted';
    grant_type="refresh_token";

}
$refresh_token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token" -Method POST -Body $refresh_body
$access_token = $refresh_token.access_token 


$title = "Scan.pdf"
$description = "scan"
$parentfolder = "redacted" #folder ID where to save
$inputmime = "application/vnd.google-apps.document" # 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/mime-types more on mime types here
$togoogle = "S:\Building_Permit_Tool\Working\0\*.pdf"

##The body must be formatted EXACTLY as below. Any extra linebreaks within 
the boundaries will cause Google to return a 400 error
$GUploadBody = @"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
"name": "$title",
"parents": [{
"id":"$parentfolder" 
}],
"mimeType": "$inputmime",
"description": "$description"


}
--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf

$togoogle
--BOUNDARY--

"@
## End HTTP Body

$GBodySize = ($GUploadBody | Measure-Object  -property length -sum).Sum     #Calculates the size in bytes of the HTTP POST body, necessary for Content-    Length in the request header 

#Request headers
$Guploadheaders = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $access_token" 
                "Content-type" = 'text/plain; boundary="BOUNDARY"'
                "Content-Length" = "$GBodySize"
                }

$GUploadURI  = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media"


$uploadrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -method POST -uri $GUploadURI -body     $GUploadBody -Headers $Guploadheaders
$uploadrequest
```

Comment: In your script, it seems that a file path is directly used in the request body. So for example, if you want to upload file, how about converting the file to base64 and upload it? By the way, ``"parents": [{"id":"$parentfolder"}]`` is used for Drive API v2. If you want to use Drive API v3, please use ``{"parents":["$parentfolder"]}``.

Comment: I gave that a try and I'm still just uploading text. It's an untitled file in the root directory and it looks like this https://imgur.com/QkgV3Ux